# Enonic xp custom property file

Tags: content-management-system

I'm using [Enonic XP.](https://enonic.com/)

I'm trying to add custom config file with some data for test and dev installation.

I've already checked documentation but, didn't find any related answer.

So is there any way to get values form property file?

Comment: Where do you want to retrieve the properties? In a javascript controller?

Comment: I've fixed this via invocation of java code

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this via invocation of java code form enonic server side js code.